# PS3 controller won't connect to ps3

Tags: ps3, controllers

I had this ps3 controller for a year. Now it won't connect. I plugged in the cable and pushed the PS3 main menu button but unable to connect the ps3. Tried with all the other cables too. I also tried reset button but still no connection to ps3. Then i thought it was a battery that need to be replaced so I replaced it. The result is the same.
I dont know what the hell is going with my ps3?

Comment: Have you tried the other USB slot on the PS3? Could be a cable problem...

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this problem too. Try plugging it in your PC (like you would charge it or something like that), pull it out and then walk towards your ps3. (Or just put your pc next to your playstation if you have a laptop).
I don't know why but when I did this, the controller suddenly connected to my ps3 again without complaining. (I guess the PC screws with the sync or something).